# Error registering the ip of the user registering in my application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web

I try to register the user's ip, but the code gives me an error

```
public async void RegistrarIp()
{
   string Host = Dns.GetHostName();
   IPAddress[] ip = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Host);
   var IpUsuario = ip[1].ToString();

   Ip IpUser = new Ip();      
   IpUser.Ip1  = IpUsuario;

   _context.Add(IpUsuario);
   await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type 'string' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model.'

And this is the model of my table ip of the database that I have

```
public partial class Ip
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string? Cod { get; set; }
   public string Ip1 { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

the error occurs specifically in the line _context.Add(IpUsuario);

if you need more information tell me

Comment: `_context.Add(IpUser);`?

Comment: Please translate your question title to English.

Answer (score 1):

`IpUsuario` is a string (`var IpUsuario = ip[1].ToString();`)and there is not entity setup for this type (and I would say there should not be). It seems that you want to add `IpUser`:

```cs
_context.Add(IpUser);
```